# Java: InetAddress.getLocalHost(); throws java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, networking, localhost, inetaddress

Im having a problem running my Java application:
When the following line gets executed, it thows an exception:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

The following exception gets thrown:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ????????: ????????
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1506)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ????????
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
... 1 more
```

I know that this is a problem with my local machine since it works on my virtual machines and other devices. I'm using Windows 10 and my hosts file is the default (non edited). What do the question marks mean? What could I try to fix this?

Comment: Does your host currently have an IP address?

Comment: Do you mean a external address? Yes, it does.

Comment: What happens if you do `ping 127.0.0.1` in a command window?

Comment: @VGR It executes the command without problems. Same with „ping localhost“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was: My hostname consisted of cyrillic letters. A user on Discord explained it to me like that:

> this seems to be a limitated at the C function getaddrinfofunction
>   [12:14] which does make sense, considering cyrillic isn't a valid DNS
>   name, so it's following RFC. [12:14] (even though hostname != dns name
>   techically, but nuances). [12:15] RFC 952 and RFC 1123 have details
>   info on it